# Regex that gets me string, given beginning and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build a function with 3 parameters:

```
var function = searchMyRegex(begin_marker, end_marker, text) { ... }
```

I need a RegExp that will give me certain string, given the beginning and end, but it will me the shortest version, meaning that neither the beginning nor the end will be in between the 2 markers

For instance

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum ipsum sit amet amet adipisicing elit"
```

If BEGIN is `ipsum` and END is `amet`, I want to get in return `ipsum sit amet`, not `ipsum ipsum sit amet amet`

The way I tried it to solve myself was like this:

```
new RegExp(begin_marker + "[^" + end_marker + "]*\ " + end_marker);
```

But this does not seem to work, and Im not sure why.

Comment: Hint: Search for *non-greedy* matching. Goto https://regex101.com/ and try out `.*` vs `.*?`

Comment: What's the difference between both matches you mentioned in last line ?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @Rahul It's not grabbing the first `ipsum` and the second `amet`, only the "inner-most" matching portion.

Comment: @le_m: That will match first `ipsum` and first `amet`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put my implementation. I updated the question.

Comment: Why use a regex instead of simply using the search() and substr() string functions?

Comment: Your example has 5 quotation marks; it doesn't work because it has syntax errors.

Comment: Could you provide some more examples ?

Comment: Sorry, I messed it at pasting. The syntax locally is correct. About "str.search", i thought it does use regexp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this kind of construct:

```
ipsum(?:(?!ipsum).)*?amet
```

`(?:(?!ipsum).)*?` checks if each position after `ipsum` and before `amet` isn't the start of an other `ipsum`.

With the non-greedy quantifier `*?`, the match stop at the first `amet` occurrence.

---

Note that the previous technique needs to perform a test with a lookahead for each position. If you deal with a long string, you can also play with character classes to be more efficient:

```
ipsum[^ia]*(?:i(?!psum)[^ia]*|a(?!met)[^ia]*)*amet
```

However it's less easy to build this pattern dynamically.

---

When the markers are words (i.e. that start and end with word characters), you can limit the number of positions tested with the lookahead like this:

```
\bipsum\W+(?:(?!ipsum\b)\w+\W+)*?amet\b
```

The lookahead is only tested at the start of words. This one can be easily build dynamically.

Comment: You are right. It escaped me. I was checking for first marker **anywhere after** first marker. Whereas it should be before second marker.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks!